# Best topics in Quantum Information and Quantum Optics to research during PhD

Tags: quantum-information, education, quantum-optics

I am searching for good (hot) topic in Quantum Inforamation and Quantum Optics for PhD research. I need suggestion that which direction i should go that later have good scope (good for publishing articles etc).  In my masters I have done research on entanglement of bipartite system and its application in low temperature physics.

I would like to join IQC University of Waterloo later for Postdoc, so if anyone have information that which direction in Quantum Information will help me to get accepted there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about educational or career advice.